# How many numbers we didn't cut?

Tags: combinatorics

We write the numbers $1, 2, 3,...., 780$ on a circle in this order and we cut the numbers for seven to seven starting with 6.

So we start with 6, 13, 20 and so on. When we go trough the numbers for the second time we count the cut numbers. For example, on the second time we cut 3, 10, 17,....

We stop when we cut again 6. How many numbers we didn't cut?

My answer is 0 but it's a little bite strange

First time we cut  6, 13,..., 776

Second time we cut 3, 10,...., 780

Third time we cut 7, 14,...,777

Fourth time we cut 4, 11,..., 774

Fifth time we cut 1, 8,..., 778

Sixth time we cut 5, 12,....,775

Seventh time we cut 2, 9,...,779

And now we cut 6 agains, so we cut all the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not strange that your answer is $0$. It is in fact quite obvious. Here is a proof:
You know that all natural numbers are of the form $7k,7k+1,7k+2$ ... $7k+6$.
Starting from $6$, you have eliminated all numbers of the form $7k+6$. Starting from $3$, all numbers of form $7k+3$ have been eliminated. Similarly, you have eliminated all numbers of form $7k,7k+1,7k+2$ ... $7k+6$ until you start over from number $6$ again. This clearly implies that all natural numbers have now been eliminated. Thus your answer is $0$.
This works for all natural numbers not of the form $7k$, not only till $780$.

Answer (score 3):

If the numbers are relatively prime (like your $n = 780$ and $k = 7$), the "not crossed out" numbers will always be none. By [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) there are integers $a, b$ such that $a n + b k = \gcd(n, k)$. By adding $n$ (one full round) enough times to the above, you see that you cross out exactly the multiples of $\gcd(n, k)$ (shifted by your starting point).